# how do operating system call bios functions?

Tags: operating-system

since we know that operating system works in protected mode
and BIOS works in a Real mode ( 16 bit). so when an interrupt is called from
either Operating System or application program, does CPU switch mode back and forth everytime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general; hardware is capable of doing lots of things at once (playing sounds while generating 3D graphics while sending data to network while transferring data to multiple disks while waiting for user input while all CPUs are busy doing actual processing); and BIOS functions are not capable of allowing more than one thing to happen at time (e.g. will waste 100% of CPU time waiting for a hard disk controller to transfer data while the CPU does nothing and while nothing else can use any other BIOS service for anything).

For this reason alone, BIOS services are not usable and not used by any modern OS (except briefly during boot).

Of course it's not the only reason - no IO prioritisation, no support for hot-plug of any kind, no support for power management, no support for system management (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T. ), no support for GPU, no support for any sound card (other than "PC speaker beep"), no support for networking (excluding PXE), no support for IO APICs, etc. Ironically, out of all of the problems, "BIOS services are designed for real mode" is the least important problem because it's the only problem that an OS can work around.

Instead, each OS has native drivers that don't have any of these limitations.

*Note: this is partly why it's relatively easy for modern operating systems to support UEFI (where none of the BIOS services exist at all) - for most, they replace the boot loader/boot code and don't need to change much else.*